# Cant get contacts given name and family name on ICS

Tags: android, android-contacts

I have this code for getting a contacts first name and family name:

```
                uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                Cursor curName = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId, null, null);
                if (curName.getCount() > 0){
                    curName.moveToFirst();
                    String nameGiven = curName.getString(curName.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
                    String nameFamily = curName.getString(curName.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
                    log += nameGiven + ", " + nameFamily + ": ";
                }
```

I only have one contact so I dont need a loop.
On an 2.3.5 device it works ok, returning the correct names. But on a 4.0.4 device it returns null for both fields, but if requesting the Display Name it provides it correctly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: have you tested to print all contents? the other device may have data saved in a wrong place. Or try to use RawContacts. Sadly there are many differences in the way each device handles contacts.

Comment: I've tried to print all the table, all data# are null.
I'll try to use RawContacts.

Answer (score 2):

Well, _ID in data table and contacts table are two different things. So you
should use **raw_contacts_id** instead of **_id** when querying the data table.

Let me throw in a quick piece of code to get you started

```
// projection
String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME};

String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ?"; 
String[] whereParameters = new String[]{this.contact_id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE};

//Request
Cursor contacts = this.resolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, where, whereParameters, null);

//Iteration
if (contacts.moveToFirst()) { 
    //code here, E.g
                String nameGiven = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
                String nameFamily = contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));

                //log += nameGiven + ", " + nameFamily + ": "; 

} 
contacts.close();
```

Comment: I was reassigned and could no check this yet, i will get to it as soon as i'll get back to this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think query for cursor need to fix, i usually use like this

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);
if (c.moveToFirst()){
    // get your code to get content on that cursor ex: c.getString(0)
}
```

please check at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) 
hope this can help you.